Regression with dependent observations of only one individual
Last week, I received a task to plan an analysis that my team wishes to perform.
My objective is to measure if one physician agrees with the outputs that a certain tool generates for a set of N medical images. For this, I'll have him look at each image and each model output and answer a brief questionnaire. My Y variable will likely be binary (agrees/disagrees) or on a Likert scale (1-5); I haven't decided yet. The other X variables will be answers to other questions, and I want to explain the Y variability with the X factors, e.g., see which factors are relevant for the physician's agreement.
My initial idea was to use a Generalized Linear Model (GLM), but my observations won't be independent. While I can ask the physician to wait a period between, let's say, 10 questionnaires to try to reduce carryover effects, there's no guarantee that (1) he will actually do that and (2) this will be effective, because, despite philosophical issues, he is still the same person. I can proceed this way and try to test for independence, but if this assumption doesn't hold, what can I do?
Upon some preliminary research, I thought of some options, but since I'm not familiar with them, I would love to get some feedback and, if possible, some references.

Adding a random term in a GAMLSS model – would this be viable? Or maybe using a Generalized Linear Mixed Model (GLMM)? Would this make sense if I have only one cluster variable (one specialist)?

Using a time series regression analysis, something like $$Y_t \sim Y_{t-1} + X1_t + X2_t + ...$$ This option strikes me as overly complicated, and also, I'm not quite sure that I'll be able to answer my question with it.




My Y variable will likely be binary (agrees/disagrees) or on a Likert scale (1-5)

I'd recommend the Likert scale since it's more informative. For analysis you can use an ordinal logistic model. https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/
Now for your options:
1 does not make sense, as you have nothing to estimate random effect variance and even if you did you still have to model time effects within each group. Option 2 might work but assuming positive auto-correlation splines like the ones used in R-package mgcv might be a more useful tool. See here: Generalized Additive Model interpretation with ordered categorical family in R (Make sure to follow the links to the documentation)
They can also be used as a type of random effect. See here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.9-1/topics/random.effects, basically s(...,bs="re").
Of course having only one physician remains a major limitation.

Thank you very much for the answer! I just took a brief look at the links and the ordinal logistic model might be what I was looking for, I'll take my time to study it further.
